# Biblioteca SoftwareSerial para Galileo

Tags: arduino

Bom dia, gostaria de saber como utilizar a biblioteca SoftwareSerial no Galileo Gen 2, ou alternativas para poder utilizar a shield ICOMSAT 1.1 no Galileo.
Obrigado.